# How to make an API request with another API result in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, api, async-await, request, axios

I want to make another API with data from the last API and i don't know how to make a multiple request with axios. I tried something but it didn't display something. I want to display on my route data from the last API.

This is to make another simplest API.

```
async function temperature() {

    this.start = '2017-01-01';
    try {
        this.latlongdata = await axios.get('https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=' + WEATHER_KEY + '&q=' + 'navodari');
        this.lat = latlongdata.data.location.lat;
        this.lon = latlongdata.data.location.lon;
        console.log(lat);

        this.stationdata = await axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/stations/nearby?lat=' + this.lat + '&lon=' + this.lon + '&limit=1&key=' + STATION_KEY);
        this.station = stationdata.data.data[0].id;

        this.tempdata = await axios.get('https://api.meteostat.net/v1/history/daily?station=' + this.station + '&start=' + this.start + '&end=' + this.start + '&key=' + STATION_KEY);
        return this.tempdata;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

class WeatherController {

    index ({ response }) {
        response.send(temperature());
    }
}

module.exports = WeatherController
```

I'm wanting to display the entire API from `this.tempdata`.

Comment: "this doesn't work." - how is it not working? Are there any errors reported?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i'l fix that, it didn't display something on the screen. The entire page is blank.

Comment: How is `WheatherController` used? Notice that `temperature()` returns a promise - maybe `response.send` cannot handle that?

Comment: WeatherController is a route on my host
'const vreme = '/vreme'
Route.get(vreme, 'WeatherController.index')'

Comment: You need to step-through it with your debugger. Is anything displayed in your browser's console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preface: Given that `async` and `Promise<T>` makes the correct use of using types in JavaScript more important, it's a good demonstration of why more programmers should be using TypeScript.

Short answer: you're returning a `Promise<T>` (I assume `T` is `object`) from `temperature()` and then passing it into ExpressJS's `Response.send` function, but `send` does not accept `Promise` objects.

The `Response.send` function accepts a single argument of type `Buffer | String | Array | object`. This is documented here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send <sub>(while *technically* `Promise<T>` is an `object`, it isn't a JSON-style object with enumerable properties, which is what `send` expects)</sub>.

The fix is simple: change your Controller action to `await` the `temperature()` result first (i.e. to resolve the `tempdata` object) before passing it into `response.send`.

```
async index( { response } ) {
    let temperatureData = await temperature();
    response.send( temperatureData );
}
```

Unrelated critiques:
* you should not store local values using `this.` inside your `temperature()` function because it introduces concurrency-related bugs into your program. Always avoid mutating shared state.
* you should rename the `temperature()` function to `getTemperature()`, or even `getTemperatureAsPromise()` to be ultra clear so users know how to use it as you’re not using JSDoc or TypeScript.